# In Windows, sharing a folder requires IIS? I cannot see share option!

Tags: windows, iis, network-shares

I want to share a folder on local network. While I right click, and select Sharing and Security, I don't see a share option. There are only three tabs General, Security, Customize. How do I share a folder? I don't have IIS on my system. Is it necessary for sharing?

Comment: What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: XP Professional Version 2002 SP 3 The folder is on the local machine. File and Printer Sharing is enabled under network configuration. Still, I don't see the sharing option. :-(

Answer (score 3):

In your network settings if you dont have file and printsharing ticked for the adapter then it won't show the tab

Comment: File and Printer sharing is ticked. But still I don't see the option when I right click a folder. I am the Admin for this system.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Windows is this? If a desktop OS, which edition is this (Home, Pro, Business, Ultimate, etc)? Are you a local administrator? Is this folder on a local drive or a remote network drive?

In business versions of Windows 7 and Server 2008 you should normally see 5 tabs when you look at properties of a local folder: General, Sharing, Security, Previous Versions, Customize. Depending on your permissions and teh edition/version of Windows you may see less or more.

IIS isn't required for folder sharing, File and Printer Sharing under network configuration is.

Comment: XP Professional Version 2002 SP 3

The folder is on the local machine. File and Printer Sharing is enabled under network configuration. Still, I don't see the sharing option. :-(